# Does Adobe live cycle provide support to convert pdf to docx?

Tags: adobe, livecycle

I checked the `Adobe pdf library` by `Datalogics` but it does not provide `API` to convert `pdf` to `docx`. Can someone tell if `Adobe live-cycle` does?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/11.0/Services/WS92d06802c76abadb76c48dfe12dbeb3e281-7fe7.2.html) for the PDF Generation service that is part of Adobe LiveCycle ES4 lists that DOCX is a supported format (on Windows only) that it can convert PDF to. LiveCycle still depends on Acrobat XI Pro being installed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
You can only convert PDF to Word document directly from Acrobat XI or later versions and not directly from Livecycle.